# how to display x and y error bars using openpyxl?

Tags: openpyxl

I am working on a project that requires the generation of xy plots in Excel. The x and y values have standard deviations associated with them. I would like to display both the x and y standard deviations as error bars. I can get the each of the error bars to display individually, but not both at the same time. 
Below is an example of the code. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
D201_avgX = Reference(resultsws,min_col=D201_avg_col,min_row=2,max_col=D201_avg_col,max_row=smprow_n)
D201_stdevX = NumDataSource(NumRef(Reference(resultsws,min_col=D201_stdev_col,min_row=2,max_col=D201_stdev_col,max_row=smprow_n)))
D201_stdev = ErrorBars(plus = D201_stdevX,minus = D201_stdevX,errBarType = 'both',errDir = 'x', errValType = 'cust')
D199_avgY = Reference(resultsws,min_col=D199_avg_col,min_row=1,max_col=D199_avg_col,max_row=smprow_n)
D199_stdevY = NumDataSource(NumRef(Reference(resultsws,min_col=D199_stdev_col,min_row=1,max_col=D199_stdev_col,max_row=smprow_n)))
D199_stdev = ErrorBars(plus = D199_stdevY,minus = D199_stdevY,errBarType = 'both',errDir = 'y', errValType = 'cust')
D201_D199_ser = SeriesFactory(D199_avgY,D201_avgX,title_from_data=True)
D201_D199_ser.marker.symbol = 'circle'
D201_D199_ser.graphicalProperties.line.noFill = True
D201_D199_ser.errBars = D201_stdev
D201_D199_ser.errBars = D199_stdev


D201_D199_chart = ScatterChart()
D201_D199_chart.series.append(D201_D199_ser)
D201_D199_ser.trendline = Trendline(dispRSqr=True)
D201_D199_chart.x_axis.title = 'D201'
D201_D199_chart.y_axis.title = 'D199'
D201_D199_chart.height = 10
D201_D199_chart.width = 15
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the implementation isn't perfect: it's based on the specification and this isn't clear on some details. I suggest you create a relevant chart in Excel or similar and look at the generated XML. You should be able to create the same structure using openpyxl, which attempts to faithfully implement the spec. If there are any problems then please submit a bug report or pull request.